# Removing multiple files with same prefix (argument list too long)

Tags: command-line, file-management

I've tried using answers given on here, and it doesn't seem to be working. Below are the commands I tried to remove all files with the index.php prefix in this directory on my CentOS system. The first two seem to have run but didn't do anything?

```
$ find . -prune -name 'index.php.*' -exec rm {} +
$ find . -prune -name 'index*' -exec rm {} +
$ rm index.php*
-bash: /usr/bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

Comment: remove the `-prune` from your `find`  command and you'll be fine

Comment: Also, no need for `-exec rm`, you can use `find . -name 'index.php' -delete`

Comment: I tried running that command @pLumo . It runs and immediately finishes, but doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I think I got it. I had to add the * at the end of the index.php. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @pLumo please don't post answers as comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume we have this test data set of test files:

```
$ tree
.
├── index.php
├── index.php.bar
├── index.php.foo
├── keppme.php
└── level1
    ├── index.php
    ├── index.php.l1
    ├── keepme.php
    └── level2
        ├── index.php
        ├── index.php.foo
        └── keepme.php
```

Delete all files starting with `index.php`:

```
$ find . -type f -name 'index.php*' -delete
```

Then test files looks like:

```
$ tree
.
├── keppme.php
└── level1
    ├── keepme.php
    └── level2
        └── keepme.php
```

Delete those with something added after `.php` extension (like `lindex.php.foo`) but keep `index.php`:

```
$ find . -type f -name 'index.php.*' -delete
```

Then test data shows:

```
$ tree
.
├── index.php
├── keppme.php
└── level1
    ├── index.php
    ├── keepme.php
    └── level2
        ├── index.php
        └── keepme.php
```

Instead using `-delete` option you can also choose `xargs` to delete files in parallel.
Sometimes for big file collection to delete this can speedup whole process but not always.

Run `rm` command on every core/cpu with max `100` files per `rm` invocation:

```
$ find . -type f -name 'index.php.*' -print0 | xargs -r0 -P $(nproc) -n 100 rm
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you only want to delete the `index*` files in the *current* directory, and this is why you use `-prune`.

By using `-prune` on *all* found pathnames, you effectively stop `find` from descending into `.`, the top-level search path. Neither of your `find` commands would therefore do anything.

To delete all the `index*` files in the current directory (but not below), use either the standard

```bsh
find . ! -path . -prune -type f -name 'index*' -exec rm {} +
```

or the non-standard

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'index*' -delete
```

or, just do a shell loop:

```bsh
for name in ./index*; do rm "$name"; done
```

The above shell loop would not test for file type as `-type f` does with `find`.  To do that:

```bsh
for name in ./index*; do
   [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -L "$name" ] && rm "$name"
done
```

Or, with `zsh`:

```bsh
for name in ./index*(.N); do rm $name; done
```

or

```bsh
autoload -U zargs
zargs -r -- index*(.N) -- rm --
```

... which calls `rm` as few times as possible.

Comment: In `zsh`, see also `zmodload zsh/files; rm -f -- index*(.)` to get a `rm` builtin. If you're going to use the `N` qualifier with `zargs`, then you should also use the `-r` option.

Answer (score 0):

In this case

> ```
> $ rm index.php*
> -bash: /usr/bin/rm: Argument list too long
> ```

you can try this instead

```
$ printf "%s\0" index.php* | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Assuming `printf` is built into the shell. It's not on OpenBSD's `ksh` or `sh` shell, for example (but as the user in the question is using CentOS, they would probably be ok).

Answer (score 0):

Commands to remove files start with a specific name:

```
a) rm -rf <file name>*   (in case it gives an error **Argument list too long** then use option b)

b) find . -type f -name '<file name>*' -delete
```

Note: In my case file name are started with `sess_`

Comment: This answer is not helpful, find will also die on argument list too long. Why is your answer an improvement to the already accepted answer?

Comment: @number9 I have checked both command with around 100690 records. First one gave error and second one executed successfully. Although it takes a bit time. So I thought let post both answers.